# How can I install oracle client on arm device

Tags: oracle, go, arm

How can I install oracle client on arm  device
I want to use go on arm device  to connect the oracle server

Comment: Can you be more specific about your arm device? There is a "development preview" version of the Oracle instant client for Oracle Linux 64-bit Arm for Raspberry Pi 3 and 4 [here](https://www.oracle.com/linux/downloads/linux-arm-downloads.html). I've used the instant client before but not that version.

Answer (score 3):

the short asnwer to your question is: you can't.

The long answer is not just one answer.

It depends on your needs.

As an example, if you need to use sql developer you can install it (it runs on Java) and connect to the oracle database using jdbc driver.

Instead of sqldeveloper you can use sqlcl + oracle jdbc client.

As last resource you can run the standard oracle client in an emulated environmnet but this is not a good solution because of performance, stability and full compatibility

Comment: For future readers: this answer is no longer true. Oracle Instant Client was just released on Linux ARM64

Comment: @ChristopherJones - doesn't work on my raspberry. following official instructions :-(

Comment: @kerfuffle https://twitter.com/GeraldVenzl/status/1390007812630061057

Comment: @ChristopherJones: "oracle-instantclient19.10-basiclite-19.10.0.0.0-1.aarch64.rpm is for architecture aarch64 ; the package cannot be built on this system"

Comment: Tried the ZIP file?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Instant Client for Linux ARM64 just got released.  It is available from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-arm-aarch64-downloads.html

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)